# Google Ads SDK 60% CPU usage while scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uitableview, ads

I load ads when the user scrolls to the cell where the ad should be. I have a problem that the application starts to lag a lot and the device heats up. When profiling the application in Time Profiler, I noticed that ~ 50-60% is occupied by some object of the GADPostNotification class. **Am I somehow loading ads wrong?** Why does this object occupy so much CPU resources when the UITableView is fast and ads are loaded, what does it do?

Google Ads SDK Version: 8.3.0

[Time Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q32gD.png)

Comment: Nobody can tell since you not showing a single line of code.

Comment: I just send a GAMRequest when the user scrolls every 10 cells. indexPath.row% 10 == 0

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Seeing something similar.

Comment: @Peter Hi, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by reducing the number of native and/or banner ads. Each native/banner ad has a WKWebView and many WKWebViews take CPU resources